# Please explain how we arrive at this statistical result

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

While solving a derivation in statistical mechanics I came across a result which was derived from expression:
$p\propto \exp{( -\frac{C_{V}}{2k T^{2}} \Delta{T^{2}}- \frac{1}{2kT \kappa _{T} V}\Delta{V^{2}}})$

The result is  which is written after writing one line which goes as:
which shows that the fluctuations in T and V are *statistically independent, Gaussian variables!*. A quick glance at above equation yields:
$\overline{(\Delta{T^{2}})}=\frac{kT^{2}}{C_{V}}, \overline{(\Delta{V^{2}})}=kT \kappa _{T} V$
Where bar over T and V represents average.
I don't understand how *statistically independent Gaussian variables* led to this result and what are *statistically independent Gaussian variables*. Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), often called *normal* distribution, is a (continuous) [probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) of the form,
$$
f_X\left(x\vert\mu,\,\sigma\right)\sim A\exp\left(-\left(x-\mu\right)^2/2\sigma^2\right)
$$
for the normalization constant $A$, mean value $\mu$ and [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) $\sigma^2$.

The author assumes that the temperature and volume distributions follow normal distributions (with variances of $k_BT/C_v$ and $k_BT\kappa_TV$) that are [not correlated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), so the product of these two is [straight-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Combination_of_two_independent_random_variables):
$$
f_T\cdot f_V\sim\exp\left(-\Delta T^2/2\sigma_T^2\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\Delta V^2/\sigma_V^2\right)
$$
And with simple properties of exponentials, leads to the result given by the author.

Comment: Sir in $f_T\cdot f_V\sim\exp\left(-\Delta T^2/2\sigma_T^2\right)\cdot\exp\left(-\Delta V^2/\sigma_V^2\right)$  shouldn't the denominator contain $2 sigma_V^2$ also if we compare $ f_X \left(x\vert\mu,\,\sigma\right)\sim A\exp\left(-\left(x-\mu\right)^2/2\sigma^2\right )$ with $p\propto \exp{( -\frac{C_{V}}{2k T^{2}} \Delta{T^{2}}- \frac{1}{2kT \kappa _{T} V}\Delta{V^{2}}})$ then variances should give the result which I required.

Comment: Sir, are averages of squares of fluctuations equal to variances. If this is the case then simply comparing with probability distribution formula should give the required result.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Gaussian (or in this case, $T$ and $V$), and uncorrelated, it can be shown that 
$$f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y);$$
this assures independence.

Comment: Pardon me, does $f_{xy}$ means partial derivative with respect to x and y.

Comment: @harshitsingh no, it's a probability distribution of random variables $X$, $Y$.

Comment: OK. Please, can you explain how we got to that result in my problem using the hint you have provided. I can't seem to understand this.